# What if $\text{card}\space c_{2n} > \text{card}\space b_n$? countable uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $A$ be an uncountable set and let $B$ be a countable subset of $A$. Show that $A$ is equivalent to $A\setminus B$.
The problem I have with this exercise is that proof provided in textbook doesn't explain things enough. Here it is
Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,...\}$. Since $A$ is uncountable ,the set $A\setminus B$ is also uncountable. Let $C=\{c_1,c_2,...\}$ be a countable subset of $A\setminus B$. Now define $f:A\setminus B \to A$ by $$ f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x,       & \quad \text{if } x \notin C;\\
    c_{n+1}  & \quad \text{if } x=c_{2n+1}\space(n=1,2,...);\\
    b_n      & \quad \text{if } x=c_{2n}\space(n=1,2,...).
  \end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is one-to-one and onto, proving that $A \approx A\setminus B$.
Now what if $c_{2n}$ outnumbers ${b_n}$? Can this proof be more thoroughly explained?

Comment: What do you mean by "$c_{2n}$ outnumbers $b_n$"?  Can you phrase this in terms of cardiinalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both $B$ and $C$ are countable infinite sets; this means that, in particular, $B$ has the same cardinality as *any infinite subset* of $C$. For example, the following sets all have the same cardinality:

- The rationals.
- The integers.
- The even integers.
- The rationals between $7$ and $304$.
- The integer powers of $3$.

And so forth. So the $c_{2n}$s **can't** outnumber the $b_n$s -  the map $$c_{2n}\rightarrow b_n$$ (one of the clauses of $f$) is always a bijection from $B$ to $\{c_{2n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: I understand that because they are both countable they can't outnumber each other but you said that Rationals have the same cardinality as integers or I don't know Natural numbers, but we know that$\space\text{card}\space\mathbb{N}<\text{card}\space\mathcal{P}{(\mathbb{N})}$

Comment: @II That is true, and means that  the **reals** are uncountable; however, the rationals and integers are each countable.